# Getting number of established TCP connections per unit time in Amazon Linux (CentOS-based)

Tags: linux, linux-networking, tcp

I'm running a server in AWS on the Amazon Linux operating system (it's a variant of CentOS I've heard), and I'd like to count the number of TCP connections that get ESTABLISHED per unit time to a specific port. Is there a way to do this using the standard tools on Linux? I'm typically a Windows user, but Linux is slowly winning me over.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
netstat -anl | grep 3001 | awk '/^tcp/ {t[$NF]++}END{for(state in t){print state, t[state]} }'
```

3001 is the port number.
should give something similar to:

```
LISTEN 1
ESTABLISHED 18
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't get any output, and it goes back to the prompt. How long does it wait and count connections? I don't see any parameters for the time.

Comment: it should be immediate. do just the "netstat -anl" and you should see all the connections and their state. The rest of the command is just a manipulation to filter the result

Comment: I was actually looking for something that counts the number of established TCP connections to a port over a specific duration (like five minutes).